# I'm getting out of memory

Tags: java, xamarin

I'm using an application with three activities inside.

Every activity using an imageview inside.

When going to previous activity i'm using

```
//java
Imageview.Dispose();
finish();
super.onBackPressed();
Runtime.gc()

//xamarin
 Imageview.Dispose();
this.Finish();
Base.OnBackPress();
GC.Collect();
```

And when going to next activity

```
//java
Intent inent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
startActivity(inent);

//xamarin
StartActivity(typeof(AnotherActivity));
```

But the problem is that the memory doesnt decrease is always increase. Am i doing something wrong?

I dont want to use finishAffinity cause it makes my tabet very slow when opening a new activity.

Comment: Do you *actually* experience an OOM or does the GC simply does not do what you expect?

Comment: I know what gc is doing. But after opening and closing activities about 100 times my apk is crash. So is there any other way for navigating throw activities without the danger to getting out of memory?

Comment: depends on what you are doing, you need to either take a close look at your code and figure out where something might be retained indefinitely OR you need to create a heap dump and analyse it. Note that calling the gc manually should not be needed at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put

> GC.Collect();

before

> Base.OnBackPress();